# Subquery returned more than 1 value. Inner Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables `tbl_Category` and `tbl_Course`.

In `tbl_Category` I have rows like this:

```
 CatID CatName CatDesc
  1     Cat1   catDesc1
  2     Cat2   catDesc2
  3     Cat3   catDesc3
  4     Cat4   catDesc4
  5     Cat5   catDesc5
```

and in `tbl_course` values are like

```
CoursID Name AssignCategory AdditionalCat
 1       cou1   1             2,3
 2       cou2   2               3
 3       cou3   1             3,4
```

I need result like below

Category which contains AsignCategory and additionalcat

```
 CatID CatName CatDesc
  1     Cat1   catDesc1
  2     Cat2   catDesc2
  3     Cat3   catDesc3
  4     Cat4   catDesc4
```

Category which does not contains AsignCategory and additionalcat

```
 CatID CatName CatDesc
  5     Cat5   catDesc5
```

I am using this split function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StrSplit (@sep char(1), @s varchar(512))  
RETURNS table  
AS  
RETURN (  
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (  
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)  
      UNION ALL  
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)  
      FROM Pieces  
      WHERE stop > 0  
    )  
    SELECT pn,  
      SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s  
    FROM Pieces  
  )
```

I am using below queries form Assign category results:

```
 select * from dbo.Tbl_Category
 where catid in(select assigncategory from Tbl_Course ) 

 )

 select * from dbo.Tbl_Category
 where catid not in(select assigncategory from Tbl_Course          
 )
```

Please help me do for additional category result with above query.

Comment: There's an underlying db design issue here, if you can modify the db design I'd break out the links between courses and categories into a separate table if they can be assigned to multiple categories rather than have concatenated values. It will make your query much simpler.

Comment: what line is the error message on? why do we care about that function?

Comment: @RandomUs1r: The OP wants to use the `StrSplit` function to translate the contents of `AdditionalCat` as a comma-delimited list of category ids.  Certainly not a great schema, but this can be done.

Comment: some one made neg marking,but he very poor in sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use CROSS APPLY to make use of your `StrSplit` udf:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_Category
WHERE CatID IN(
    SELECT AssignCategory 
    FROM tbl_Course
    UNION
    SELECT CAST(split.S as int) 
    FROM tbl_Course
    CROSS APPLY dbo.StrSplit(',', AdditionalCat) as split )

SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_Category
WHERE CatID NOT IN(
    SELECT AssignCategory 
    FROM tbl_Course
    UNION
    SELECT CAST(split.S as int) 
    FROM tbl_Course
    CROSS APPLY dbo.StrSplit(',', AdditionalCat) as split )
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/746cd/6).

You can also use UNPIVOT to avoid using UNION. But since there are only 2 columns that need to be merged, UNION is probably 'good enough' for this purpose.